# data tables and table tools performance issue for large number of records

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatables, tabletools

I am using datatables for my search operation . First, I search for records .

> There are cases when I could get 3000 records .

I am using table tools to select all of the records and update them at a shot . When user clicks on **updateAll** (custom button on page), jQuery modal dialog opens and asks user to enter some values for some fields which are common to all the records . All are optional .

So, when user clicks on **update** (custom_button on dialog) I have to parse through all the records and get the values which are not provided by user and has to make a JSON object which contains 3000 objects pertaining to all the records and send it to server.

Once I receive the success response from server , I have to parse all the records and have to update them with the values which are entered in the modal dialog,and refresh the table.

I am getting selected row data using **fnGetSelected()** and then **fnGetData()** which returns array. I am looping this javascript array for getting data from rows ,making **JSON** object, update records after server call .

> This above situation is giving me huge performance issue for 3000 records.
>   In chrome page became unresponsive.But while updating few records, it's getting updated faster .

Suggest me a solution . Thank you

Comment: how can anyone provide assistance when you fail to show any code?

Comment: Use angularjs I used it with 8000 records and objects were resonably large and it worked fine on my end.

Comment: _I have to parse through all the records and get the values which are not provided by user_ why do you have to do that? why not just pass the records that require updating?

Comment: I am depicting the case of updating all the records . So,once I select all the records and click on 'updateAll', in the displayed dialog , I should enter some values which are optional . So, if user provides those values I will use them. Otherwise, they are already with rows from which I collect them.My Spring MVC controller demands list of all the rows, each contains values for each entity of a rwo.